# White screen when changing URL - Phonegap v3

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Looking around I don't expect anybody to be able to help with this.

I'm using phonegap v 3.3.0 and building an android app. Everything works perfectly so long as i don't try to navigate to any url's directly. I believe this might have something to do with the iframe loading internally.

If i use weinre directly I can confirm its with any url change:

```
 window.location.href = "/#home";
```

If this is run then it will display the white screen along with any links I click internally in the app.

Answer (score 0):

No sooner had I clicked Add question that I realised that the answer was in the question.

Its using an iFrame and after learning from the images that everything needs to be relative it dawned on me.

```
window.location.href = "/#home";
```

Will go to the root of the device, which there are no websites.

So you need a reletive path, easiest way when you're navigating using `#`'s is to use

```
window.location.href = "#home";
```